# Check certain Popen is running at first (==Checking variable is assigned)

Tags: python, process, subprocess, popen

I got a running Thread `p` in a function
and trying to check at first, whether it's already running or not

if `p` wasn't running it spits reference before the assignment error

```
from subprocess import check_output,Popen
from asyncio.subprocess import PIPE
from threading import Thread

def th():
    p= Popen([r'C:\Users\dow\Desktop\dd\StructuredOsuMemoryProviderTester.exe'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE) if p else 0
    for line in p.stdout:
        line=line.decode('utf-8')
        print(line)
while True:
    try:
        Thread(target=th).start()
//extra codes
```

**What I've tried**

- p.poll()
  this gets NameError in the same way course
- `progs = str(check_output('tasklist'))`
  checking if p is not in progs.

this have a problem briefly popping a black window with a brief delay at every checking loop

and if the process's name is long, it cuts the rest name so I think kindof unstable way

**What is a good way to check whether p is running==assigned?**

Comment: Are you trying to test whether any instance of this .exe is running or whether the .exe is running specifically from this program? If you are interested in this program only, you could create an instance of `p = None` at module level and then add `global p` to your  function. Now, `p` is defined for the check.

Comment: This code creates threads in a tight loop that all want to read the stdout of a single process? This isn't going to work so well.

Comment: p.stdout is not printing anything and just wait forever until another output so i thought  should use thread to fetching realtime data from it

Comment: loop for when error occured or need to break. if the .exe is running twice, it prints double output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to run your exe exactly once from this program. To do that you could keep some global state to let you know whether the process has been executed. Wrap that state in a lock to avoid race conditions and your code could be:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from threading import Thread, Lock

exe_has_run = False
exe_lock = Lock()

def th():
    global exe_has_run
    with exe_lock:
        if primary := exe_has_run is False:
            exe_has_run = True
            p = Popen([r'C:\Users\dow\Desktop\dd\StructuredOsuMemoryProviderTester.exe'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
    if primary:
        for line in p.stdout:
            line=line.decode('utf-8')
            print(line)


while True:  # this will blow up your process
    Thread(target=th).start()
//extra codes
```

Comment: thank you, It's clear to seeing this. and guess someday i'll get what you meant about comment